# for loop with many iterations vs for loop with fewer iterations

Tags: for-loop, iteration, big-o

Let's say we have for loop (a) that will have 100 iterations and for loop (b) that will have 50 iterations.

Which is more efficient?

I would think that (b) is more efficient because it has less iterations, but big - o for (a) and (b) are both *n*.

Am I overthinking this and misusing the concept of big o ?

Comment: Big-O analysis is not applicable to this situation, as it is based on the number of inputs. You are right that 50 iterations is more efficient than 100 iterations, but that's not a question of Big-O.

Comment: Two algorithms are both O(n) don't mean that they have the same running time.

Answer (score 0):

To learn more about in which sense having fewer iterations is more efficient, read about loop unrolling (or loop unwinding).

Answer (score 0):

Big O tells the upper bound of a functions growth rate. Its only an estimation.

In your case both the loops (or in fact the same loop with different number of iterations ) have same time complexity of "O(n)". i.e. the performance of the loops is directly proportional to the number of inputs. (plotting a linear Time vs inputs graph)

- Two different functions/algos having same complexity for a particular case (worst/best/average) only means that they have same "growth rate" for that case and not that they will perform exactly same in actual run.

so in actual measurements, same loop with 50 (n=50) iterations will take less time than loop with 100 (n=100) iterations.

may be your are not appreciating that its a theoretical mechanism for growth rate/performance estimation for a function/algorithm.